# Spring MVC Thymeleaf Error: Parameter conditions not met for actual request parameters

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC Thymeleaf and trying to get some simple input/output working. The below code is supposed to accept text input, then output it when 
the "Submit" button is pressed. However, I get the following error:

> org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException: Parameter conditions "submitInput" not met for actual request parameters:

**InputHolder.java**

```
public class InputHolder {
    public String input;
}
```

**GreetingController.java**

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting", params={"submitInput"})
    public String recieveInput(final InputHolder inputHolder, final BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("input", inputHolder.input);
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

**greeting.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="/greeting" th:object="${inputHolder}" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <div>
                    <label for="basicInput"></label>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{basicInput}" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" name="submitInput">Submit Input</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p th:text="'Output: ' + ${input}"></p>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, you are submitting the form as `POST` and the controller method you showed is for `GET`. Does this even work? I am wondering...

Comment: No, that does not work :P Sorry I'm just new to this software and made a lot of mistakes in the above code, as described in my comment to @Malhar. Anyway I see what I did wrong and it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller class you are using "params={"submitInput"}" which means the url expects that parameter.
Seems like you are not passing expected parameter "submitInput" in url, like

localhost:8080/{appname}/greeting?submitInput={someinput}

Comment: Ok, yes, thanks! As I said I'm new to Spring, so yeah I basically just didn't understand the purpose of the `params` modifier. I did still need to make a few more changes to get this to work though, which I'll list here for reference:
1. `input` should have been private and had a getter and setter.
2. `basicInput` should have been called `input`, like how it is in the `InputHolder` class
3. the `bindingResult` parameter was unnecessary and thus removed