# Spring: Parameter conditions "loanTitle" not met for actual request parameters

Tags: java, spring

Java Spring MVC. I can't open url without a parameter. I found suggestions in Internet([Spring MVC Thymeleaf Error: Parameter conditions not met for actual request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445036/spring-mvc-thymeleaf-error-parameter-conditions-not-met-for-actual-request-para), http://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping), but they didn't help me.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/loans/")
public class LoanController {

    @Autowired 
    LoanDAO loanDAO;

    @GetMapping(value= "objectloan", params = {"loanTitle"})
    public String index(Model theModel, HttpSession session, @RequestParam(value = "loanTitle", required = false, defaultValue = "") Optional<String> loanTitle)
    {
....
    }
```

URL works

> http://localhost:8080/college/loans/objectloan?loanTitle=test

URL with error

> http://localhost:8080/college/loans/objectloan

Error:

```
Type Status Report
Message Parameter conditions "loanTitle" not met for actual request parameters:
Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
```

Comment: try define @GetMapping(value= "objectloan")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `loanTitle` might not present in your query url,try to remove `params = {"loanTitle"}` in your controller method

```
    @GetMapping(value= "objectloan")
    public String index(Model theModel, HttpSession session, @RequestParam(value = "loanTitle", required = false, defaultValue = "") Optional<String> loanTitle)
    {
....
    }
```